# Moqui Authorization

Tags: moqui

I am trying to access Moqui entities using REST API. Here is an the example call.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/m1/products/default
Accept: application/application/json
Authorization: Basic am9obi5kb2U6bW9xdWk=
```

I am getting the following response

```
{
  "errorCode": 403,
  "errors": "User john.doe is not authorized for View on Entity mantle.product.Product"
}
```

However calls to mantle-usl services work fine as shown in following example

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/s1/mantle/facilities/
Accept: application/application/json
Authorization: Basic am9obi5kb2U6bW9xdWk=

[
  {
    "facilityId": "ZIRET_WH",
    "pseudoId": "ZIRET_WH",
    "facilityTypeEnumId": "FcTpWarehouse",
    "ownerPartyId": "ORG_ZIZI_RETAIL",
    "facilityName": "Ziziwork Retail Warehouse",
    "assetAllowIssueOverQoh": "Y",
    "lastUpdatedStamp": 1550661258932
  }
]
```

How do I allow a user to access entities using REST API?

Comment: Please remove the authorization tokens from the code!

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It is advised that you should not include important informations like passwords, credentials, etc. on public communities like StackOverflow. *There are hackers all the way...*

Comment: Of course one should not make credentials public. In this case, the authorization token shared above is public knowledge. It is default username and password of Moqui.

Comment: Sorry then, I was wrong. I was not knowing.

Comment: @Gourav people need to be warned. But, if the host is `localhost` or ip address is in private ip pools, we can overlook the credentials being shared.

Comment: That's ok then. But it was my duty to let you know. Now the matter is resolved. No need to worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/Security#artifact-authz

The following text is copied from Moqui documentation.

*The first step to configure artifact authorization is to create a group of artifacts. This involves a ArtifactGroup record and a ArtifactGroupMember record for each artifact, or artifact name pattern, in the group.*

*For example here is the artifact group for the Example app with the root screen (ExampleApp.xml) as a member of the group:*

```
<moqui.security.ArtifactGroup artifactGroupId="EXAMPLE_APP" description="Example App (via root screen)"/>
<moqui.security.ArtifactGroupMember artifactGroupId="EXAMPLE_APP" artifactTypeEnumId="AT_XML_SCREEN" inheritAuthz="Y" artifactName="component://example/screen/ExampleApp.xml"/>
```

If you are in hurry, read on.

Try adding the following snipped in ExampleZzzDemoData.xml

```
<moqui.security.ArtifactGroupMember artifactGroupId="EXAMPLE_APP" artifactName="mantle\..*"
                                        nameIsPattern="Y" artifactTypeEnumId="AT_ENTITY" inheritAuthz="Y"/>
```

**Note:** *This is not for a production system. It is a huge security risk to give access to all entities to a single role. Make sure you take time and plan authorization.*